# Issue with Bash script, i am new to bash, unable to understand the syntax error

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, scripting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to bash scripting, I am writing a script that will deploy a new artifact to AWS Elasticbeanstalk, rather than going to AWS UI, and developers taking a long time. please see below and let me know if I am doing anything wrong. I am worried about this part:
if [ "$1" = "help" ] HELP <<EOF
then
read -r -d ''
Usage:
\t$(basename $0) list - list all applications
\t$(basename $0) deploy    - deploy artifact to an environment
EOF
die "$HELP"
exit 0
fi

Running this command to run the script:
**AWS_PROFILE=default ARTIFACT_BUCKET=myawsstudybucket ARTIFACT_NAME=artifact1.zip ./deploy.sh deploy demo-app Demoapp-env artifact.zip**

```
#!/bin/bash

PROFILE=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account)
RED='\033[0;31m'
COLOR_OFF='\033[0m'

if [ -z "$PROFILE" ] 
then
    echo "Credentials missing"
else 
    region=$(aws configure get region)
fi

if [ "$1" = "list" ]
then 
    echo $(aws elasticbeanstalk describe-applications --query "Applications[].ApplicationName")
    exit 0
fi

if [ "$1" = "help" ] HELP <<EOF
then
    read -r -d ''
    Usage:
    \t$(basename $0) list - list all applications
    \t$(basename $0) deploy <app-name> <environment-name> <local-artifact-path> - deploy artifact to an environment
    EOF
    die "$HELP"
    exit 0
fi

die() { echo -e "$*" >&2; exit 1; }

[[ -z $EB_APP ]] && die "ERROR: Missing application name"
[[ -z $EB_ENV ]] && die "ERROR: Missing application environment"
[[ -z $EB_ARTIFACT ]] && die "ERROR: Missing application artifact location"

s3path="s3://$ARTIFACT_LOCATION/$ARTIFACT_NAME"
aws s3 cp $artifactpath $s3path

versionlabel=$(date +%s%N)
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name "$ebapp" --version-label $versionlabel --source-bundle S3Bucket=$ARTIFACT_LOCATION,S3Key=$ARTIFACT_NAME
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name $ebenv --version-label $versionlabel

echo "Deployment in progress"
while [[ "$STATUS" != OK ]] && [[ "$STATUS" != Severe ]];
do
    echo "Checking environment status"
    status=$(aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-health --environment-name $ebenv --attribute-names HealthStatus --query "HealthStatus"| tr -d '"')
    echo "Current status: $status."
    sleep 5
done

echo "Deployed successfully"
```

Comment: The reason to use this script is to deploy the new artifact version, with a multi-region option.

Comment: please reformat your post. see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: BTW, running `$(basename "$0")` over and over is pretty slow for no good reason. Consider calling it just once and storing the result in a variable, or using `"${0##*/}"` instead.

Comment: Also, don't use the `-e` argument to `echo` -- POSIX requires that it print `-e` on output, so when you use it to tell the bash version of `echo` to expand backslash-escape sequences, you're depending on optional behavior that can be turned off at either runtime or compile-time. Also see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) at [unix.se], and [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), especially the *APPLICATION USAGE* section.

Answer (score 1):

That part is definitely strange. What should the word HELP do after the `]`?

You probably wanted something like

```bash
if [ "$1" = "help" ]
then
    echo Press Enter to display the help...
    read
    cat <<-EOF
    Usage:
        $(basename $0) list - list all applications
        $(basename $0) deploy <app-name> <environment-name> <local-artifact-path> - deploy artifact to an environment
    EOF
fi
```

Note that you need the real <kbd>Tab</kbd> before the closing EOF.

Or maybe you wanted this?

```bash
die() { echo -e "$*" >&2; exit 1; }

if [ "$1" = "help" ]
then
   HELP="
    Usage:
        $(basename $0) list - list all applications
        $(basename $0) deploy <app-name> <environment-name> <local-artifact-path> - deploy artifact to an environment
"
   die "$HELP"
fi
```

Strings in quotes can be multiline.

Note that `die` must be declared before you can call it.